# Assembler-adding two variables

Tags: windows, assembly, x86

I've just tried to write my first program in assembly for x86 and I don't know why, but it doesn't make what I want. There's no errors, no communicates but the program doesn't open after pushing 'execute'. i want these program to add two variables and send back theirs sum. here's code:

```
    .386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include windows.inc
include user32.inc
include kernel32.inc

includelib user32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib

.data
a dw 1h
b dw 2h
z dw 01 dup(?),0
.data?

.code
start:
    mov ds, ax
    mov ax, a
    mov bx, b
    clc
    add ax, bx
    mov edi, offset z
    mov [edi], ax

    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, z
    int 21h

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h

end start
```

Please, help me :C

Comment: It's not clear if you're trying to compile this as 16bit code. (if so why is there a EDI in the middle?). What you wrote looks like old DOS-era assembly, it wouldn't run on any modern system. I suggest you look at more recent tutorials/books if you're trying to learn modern assembly.

Comment: You seem to be buliding a Windows executable, but the code is for DOS. That's not going to work. Find a tutorial for Windows assembly instead (IIRC MASM32 includes lots of example code).

Comment: Note that DOSBox should still be able to run this, if you insist on using DOS interrupts.

Comment: Not if assembled and linked as-is. Wrong memory model, and linking against user32.lib and kernel32.lib suggests PE as the output format, rather than a DOS-style MZ-executable.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I don't know which tutorial/book I should choose. Could you help me and recommend something?

Comment: If you can comment your code, it will help a lot; generally one comment per instruction, unless the instruction is obscure and needs two or three comments to help the reader understand it.

Answer (score 0):

[DOS function 09h](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah09) expects a string; specifically, an array of bytes, each containing the ASCII code of a character, terminated by 24h (the ASCII code of `$`). Example:

```
z   db '3$'
```

which is equivalent with:

```
z   db 33h, 24h
```

Instead, you have defined `z` as an array of words, and fill the first word with 03h (the result of 1+2). In ASCII, 03h is a [non-printing character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character).

Assembly is not some high-level language with convenient automatic type conversions. In assembly, you will have to convert the numeric value into a sequence of ASCII characters yourself.

How to do this? That has been asked numerous times already. Like here: [Assembly, printing ascii number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621258/assembly-printing-ascii-number)

Unless of course you have a convenient library with conversion functions lying around.