# Assembly Array and loop

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly

I've a problem in assembly language that I want to make loop for sum element of an array.
 Suppose an array contains 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 I have to sum all elements of the array by loop... How can I do this?

I'm trying this:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
W   DW 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
.CODE 
MAIN PROC
MOV AX, @data
MOV DS, AX

XOR AX, AX
XOR BX, BX
MOV CX, 10

ADDNOS:
ADD AX, W [BX]
ADD BX, 2
LOOP ADDNOS


;this for display
MOV DX, AX
MOV AH,2
INT 21H

MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

but something wrong in display that print from ascii (&).

Comment: May I suggest you to simply retry from scratch? I can't see a single line that it's worth keeping. Any useful answer can only be a complete solution to your homework

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Updated answer since the code in the question has been changed:**

`INT 21h / AH=2` prints a single character (note that the integer `1` and the character `'1'` are different values).
The sum of the elements in your array is 550, which requires 3 characters to print. The way to solve that is to write a routine that converts the value 550 to the string "550", and then use `INT 21h / AH=9` to print that string. How you'd go about doing that has been asked several times before on StackOverflow; see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621258/assembly-printing-ascii-number) and the answers to it.

---

**This is my answer for the original question**

For future questions, note that *"but something wrong"* is a terrible problem description. You should explain precisely in what way the code isn't behaving the way you intended.

That said, there are a number of problems with your code:

Here you're initializing `CX` to the first value in `x`. Actually, since the elements in `x` are bytes (because you used `DB`) and `CX` is a word (two bytes) you'll get `CX = 301h` (which is 769 in decimal):

```
MOV CX, x
```

---

Here you're simply moving the first element of `x` into `BX` over and over, instead of doing an addition. And again, `x` contains bytes while `BX` is a word register.

```
top:    MOV BX, [x]
```

---

The `loop` instruction decrements `CX` by 1 and jumps to the given label if `CX != 0`. By incrementing `CX` before the `loop` you're creating an infinite loop. Also, the `CMP` is useless (and I'm not sure why you're comparing against 7 since `x` only has 5 elements):

```
INC CX
CMP CX, 7
loop top
```

---

This will only work for values in the range 0-9. If the sum is >=10 it will require multiple characters. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621258/assembly-printing-ascii-number) for an example of how to convert a multi-digit number to a string that can be printed. Also, you're writing a word-sized register to a byte variable:

```
ADD BX, '0'
MOV [sum], BX
```

---

Here I'm a bit lost at what you're trying to do. If you wanted to write a single character to STDOUT you should use `INT 21h / AH = 2 / DL = character`. Note that `MOV AX,4` sets `AH=0` and `AL=4`. Also, you should end your program with `INT 21h / AX = 4C00h`:

```
display_:
    MOV DX,1
    MOV CX, sum
    MOV BX, 1
    MOV AX,4
    INT 21h
    MOV AX, 1
    INT 21h
```

Comment: Seeing `MOV [sum], BX` in the code I suspect that `MOV CX, x` rather means putting the address of __x__ in CX.

Comment: That may have been what the OP intended. But it's not what it actually means in the x86 assembly dialect used in the OP's code.

Comment: How to convert (value to string!)? I do this, `AP_:
MOV DX,0
DIV BX
ADD DX, 48
DEC SI
MOV [SI], DL
CMP AX,0
JZ EXTT
JMP AP_

EXTT:
MOV AH,9
MOV DX,SI
INT 21H
RET`  but the program doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that there is an error in the code following the `top` label.

You do `MOV BX, [x]` but I think there you should sum the item pointed by `CX` with what currently is in `BX` (that seems to store the sum). So substitute the move instruction with:

```
ADD BX, [CX]
```

Comment: `[CX]` is not a valid effective address. And `CX` is not pointing to `x` (that would require the `OFFSET` operator in MASM/TASM syntax, which this code appears to be written in).