# Counting spaces in a string, it prints the string and CX stays 0. assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

```
.model  small
.stack  100H
.data

A   db   '   this is    a test $'

.code  

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax 

    mov si, 0
    mov cx, 0  

myloop: 

    cmp A[si], '$'
    je final

    cmp  A[si], ' '   
    inc si
    je count
    jmp myloop

count:

    inc cx
    jmp myloop

final:

    mov dx, cx
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

end
```

Comment: Click "edit" below your question, select all your code, click the button with the curly braces, save your question.

Comment: Also, comment your code and learn to use a debugger. Furthermore `int21/09` expects a pointer to a string, it will not print a number.

Comment: You need to convert CX into string = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605815/how-can-i-print-0-to-100-in-assembly-language-in-emu-8086/37618809#37618809

Comment: Note that `inc si` affects the `Z` flag, and destroys the result of the comparison `cmp  A[si], ' '`. So the following `je count` is not testing what you think it does.

Comment: ...and since `si` started at `0` incrementing it will cause "not zero" so you won't ever count any spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you override the flags for the "is blank" comparison by the subsequent "inc si"

```
.model  small
.stack  100H
.data

A   db   '   this is    a test $'

.code  

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax 

    mov si, 0
    mov cx, 0  

myloop: 

    cmp A[si], '$'
    je final

    cmp  A[si], ' '   
    jne do_not_count   ; skip count if it's not a blank

count:
    inc cx             ; it is a blank, count it

do_not_count:
    inc si
    jmp myloop

final:

    ;mov dx, cx                     ; this does NOT print CX
    ;mov ah, 9
    ;int 21h

    mov dl, cl                      ; workaround: this works for cx < 10
    add dl, '0'
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h

end
```

Comment: This still does not print a number, as commented above.

Comment: you're right. to do this, in "final" CX must be converted to a decimal string, and this has to be printed.

Comment: the OP didn't really state what exactly he wanted. If  his problem is "CX stays 0", counting the spaces is the solution, not printing CX ;)