# assembly language(emu8086) convert value to the equivalent ASCII code

Tags: ascii

all

I have a project assembly code but I face a problem with converting values.

I want do loop then print the loop value to the (printer virtual device) at port 130 as “value = X” every time the loop changes. Note that you should convert the value to the equivalent ASCII code before printing it out.

Thanks.

Comment: That means you cannot send the numerical value in bytes to the printer. You have to convert the value to a string with corresponding ASCII characters and send those values.

Comment: yes, i cannot send the numerical value in bytes to the printer.

Comment: can help me, plz?

Comment: You should think how you may do it, try to it, if it does not work, search here or google about the problem, and if you finally feel blocked about it, post a question and paste a small snippet of your code that does not work, for others to help you.

Comment: It looks you are new here. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you just want an answer but people here will not welcome the idea of writing the code for you. Take some time to read the help center on how to post good questions to avoid downvotes.

Comment: Finally, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621258/assembly-printing-ascii-number?rq=1) is a similat question that may help you.