# How do I print a number in bios assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bios, real-mode

I tried many ways of doing this and was searching the internet for 2 hours, didn't find anything. Please help, new to assembly. I realised that I have to convert the number into a string, but I didn't succeed in doing so.

Last attempt:

```
pint:
    .repeat:
        mov ax, 10
        div al
        mov cl, [al]
        mov al, [ah]
        mov ah, 0Eh
        add ah, 48
        int 0x10
        sub ah, 48
        mov al, [cl]
        cmp al, 0
        je .done
        jmp .repeat
    .done:
        ret
```

Comment: Show your attempt.

Comment: Whats the langauge of assembly there alot of them NASM/MASM/FASM/SASM etc

Comment: nasm its in the tags i think

Comment: @Jester here is my last attempt, its messy and useless i got lost in it quickly... 
`pint:
 .repeat:
  mov ax, 10
  div al
  mov cl, [al]
  mov al, [ah]
  mov ah, 0Eh
  add ah, 40
  int 0x10
  sub ah, 40
  mov al, [cl]
  cmp al, 0
  je .done
  jmp .repeat
 .done:
  ret`

Comment: Here perfect reference for os develop with assembly for beginner: https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/

Comment: Use the [edit] link to add information into your question. Also,comment your code. In particular the `add/sub` 40 are not obvious. Specify how big your number is and whether it's signed or not.

Comment: @Jester sorry for the mistake, the number is supposed to be 48, because 48 is zero in ascii. I'll edit it now.

Comment: I assume the `div al` wants to divide by 10, but of course `div` uses `ax` for the dividend so that won't work. Also are you aware this method produces digits in the reverse order?

Comment: @Jester I wanted to specify ax before calling the function, and I know it would be in reverse.

Comment: Also it's unclear why you `sub ah, 48` and `mov al, [cl]` is plain simply invalid.

Comment: @NateEldredge It kinda does, but what if there's more digits than two?

Comment: Then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621258/assembly-printing-ascii-number/15621644#15621644 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos.  These are from the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) which has many other resources that you may find useful.

Comment: Use any of the 1-char-at-a-time DOS print number answers, but use a BIOS call instead of a DOS call.